# MySql запрос (ругаеться на 2 Left Join)

Tags: mysql, sql

Не выходит исправить ошибку
2 errors were found during analysis.

> This type of clause was previously parsed. (near "LEFT JOIN" at
>   position 234) Unrecognized statement type. (near "LEFT JOIN" at
>   position 234)

```
SELECT ea.attribute_id, cpei.store_id, cpei.value, cpe.entity_id 
FROM catalog_product_entity AS cpe
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_int AS cpei 
    ON cpe.entity_id = cpei.entity_id 
   AND cpei.attribute_id = 158 
WHERE cpei.value IS NULL
LEFT JOIN eav_attribute AS ea ON ea.attribute_id = 'hide';
```

Comment: для начала перенесите where в конец запроса

Comment: `WHERE cpei.value IS NULL` перенесите после последнего джойна, либо пропишите `and` вместо `where`

Comment: Ругается, кстати, не MySQL, а какой-то надстроечный парсер...

Comment: @Akina мне тоже это любопытно, я никогда всякие sqllite и тому подобное не видал. Может, че-то такое

Comment: @splash58 больше похоже что это ответ от PHP mysqli, но утверждать не буду =)

Comment: @PotroNik надо будет глянуть, но мне казалось, что она просто транслирует запросы и ответы туда-сюда без обработки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Измените согласно поставленной задачи:
1 - Если это ограничение для выборки данных, перенести его за последний join

```
SELECT ea.attribute_id, cpei.store_id, cpei.value, cpe.entity_id 
FROM catalog_product_entity AS cpe
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_int AS cpei 
ON cpe.entity_id = cpei.entity_id 
AND cpei.attribute_id = 158 
/*WHERE cpei.value IS NULL*/
LEFT JOIN eav_attribute AS ea ON ea.attribute_id = 'hide';
WHERE cpei.value IS NULL
```

2 - Если это ограничение для `Join` то заменить `where` на `and`

Comment: Поскольку условие по правой таблице, но не по полю связывания - голосую за первый вариант.